# Why should I explicitly surround with "unchecked"?

Tags: c#, casting, unchecked

Is there anyone able to explain me this strange behavior?

```
    int i = 0x1234;
    byte b1 = (byte)i;
    byte b2 = (byte)0x1234;         //error: const value '4660' can't convert to byte (use unchecked)
    byte b3 = unchecked((byte)0x1234);
    byte b4 = checked((byte)i);     //throws
    byte b5 = (byte)(int)0x1234;    //error: same as above
```

NOTE: It's an empty Console application, with *NO* arithmetic checking enabled (as default is).
Thank you everybody in advance.

EDIT: I supposed to be clear enough, but not for all.

I do know that a word can't fit into a byte. But, by default, a C# program allows certain "dangerous" operations, primarily for performance reason.

Similarly, I may sum two large integers together and having no overflow at all.

My wonder was about the compile-time error above: the b1 cast/assignment is compiled, the b2 can't compile. Apparently there's no difference, because both are Int32 having the same value.

Hope it's clear now.

Comment: I don't speak c# and I don't know what "checked" and "unchecked" mean, but I know that you can't fit a four-digit hex number in a byte.

Comment: Which behaviour is 'strange' to you? You have given us **steps to reproduce** and **actual result**, but not **expected result**.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're tripping over a part of section 7.19 of the C# 4 spec:

> Unless a constant expression is explicitly placed in an `unchecked` context, overflows that occur in integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions during the compile-time evaluation of the expression always cause compile-time errors.

Basically, the point is that even if you're happy to allow operations to overflow at *execution* time, if you're trying to use a constant expression which can't be converted to the target type *at compile time*, you have to tell the compiler that you really know what you're doing.

For example, in this case you're losing information - it'll be equivalent to

```
byte b3 = 0x34;
```

so you'd *normally* be better off just specifying that, to give you clearer code which doesn't mislead the reader. It's relatively rare that you want to overflow in a constant - most of the time you should just specify the valid value instead.

Comment: You sound like a lawyer quoting the _"section 7.19 of the C# 4 spec"_. :D

Comment: For me that's all right, but why the compiler does not take in account the "Arithmetic overflow" disabling as well?
Thank you anyway: it was just a curiosity I bumped to.

Comment: @MarioVernari: Because that's designed to change the execution-time behaviour - most C# code is probably built with that default, but most devs should still care if their *constants* overflow.

Comment: @Leito: I don't mind being a language lawyer - the spec is (to some extent, anyway) the real authority on the language, so giving a spec reference is good practice when trying to justify compiler behaviour IMO.

Comment: And I agree with you. I was just making an off-topic comment - SO users forgive me -  because it's not common to have those kind of answers, quoting sections, chapters and all. It's all credit to you. :)

Comment: @Leito: It's just a pity that there isn't a good multi-page HTML version of the full C# 4 spec online, otherwise I could include a link, as I usually do with the JLS. I believe MSDN has a version of the C# spec, but I don't think it's laid out in quite the same way...

Comment: @phoog: Thanks, fixed - and the typo of "expressions" :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a strange behaviour, the valid range for a variable of the [byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) data type is `0-255` but when you convert HEX `0x1234` value into decimal system you got `4660`.
So [unchecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)  used to control the overflow-checking integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.

You can find that `unchecked` often used in `GetHashCode()` implementation which does numeric operations to calculate the final hash code.

To summarize you should use `unchecked` when the final result value of integer-type operations is not matter but overflow could happen.

Answer (score 0):

You **shouldn't** surround this with unchecked. Unchecked allows assignment of dangerous value types to a type, which may cause overflows.

`byte b1 = (byte)i;` will cause an overflow or cast exception at runtime.
`byte b2 = (byte)0x1234;` is invalid because you can't store values larger than 0xFF in a byte.
`byte b3 = unchecked((byte)0x1234);` will place either 0x34 or 0x12 (depending on the CLR implementation) into b3, and the other byte will overflow.
`byte b4 = checked((byte)i);` is the same as `byte b1 = (byte)i;`
`byte b5 = (byte)(int)0x1234;` will cast 0x1234 to an int, and then try to cast it to byte. Again, you can't convert 0x1234 to a byte because it's too large.

Comment: Well, you're partially right, but not at all.
It's true that avoiding checks is a dangerous practice, but you should also use them with a bit of brain, IMHO.
It's NOT true, that your first assignment cause an exception. It'll throw only if you enable the "arithmetic checking" (default is off).
The third assignment I guess is wrong: it should return always 0x12.
Fourth: same considerations of the first.
Fifth: same as second.
Cheers

Comment: The third will always return 0x34, not 0x12.  And the first will only cause an exception if checking is enabled AND if the value is outside the range 0-255.