# Storing negative int and negative constant int in a byte C#

Tags: c#, int, byte, storage, constants

I wanted to know why it's possible to store a negative int into a byte but I get errors when I try to store a negative int that is constant into a byte?

Comment: The answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823268/why-should-i-explicitly-surround-with-unchecked). The constant can't be converted at compile time so you get compile error even though you can force it with `unchecked`.