# how to define uint variable as -1 in c#

Tags: c#

I have the following function written in c and working properly; but I need to convert it to c#.
There is variable called unsigned int found_at = -1 ; the equivalent in c# should be uint found_at = -1;
However I receive compiler error. Could you please guide me to solve this problem

```
unsigned int find_adjacent_values(double val, unsigned int start_here, unsigned int end_here, double *vector) {
unsigned int i = start_here, found = 0, found_at = -1;
while (i < end_here-1 && found == 0) {
    if (val >= vector[i] && val < vector[i+1]) { // check whether we found adjacent values
        found = 1;
        found_at = i;
    } else {
        i += 1;
    }
}
return found_at;
```

}

Comment: Why not just use `int`?  That would cover all possible index values and -1.

Comment: Assigning `-1` to an unsigned value is just bad practice in both languages. The intent is to write `UINT_MAX` in C,  or `uint.MaxValue` in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
uint found_at = unchecked((uint)-1);
```

Note that thanks to how two's complement numbers work, that line is equivalent to writing:

```
uint found_at = uint.MaxValue;
```

The explanation about why you need the `unchecked(...)` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7823327/613130).